# milvus-backup restore very slow , why and how to improve performance?

Tags: milvus

I try to backup and restore milvus 2.3.3 with milvus-backup 0.4 , making backup of collection with 160M entities seems pretty fast in 30min , but restore take more then 9h , please, advice if there is options to improve , the command I am using to restore is:

```
 milvus-backup restore -n mycollection --restore_index
```

P.S.
I see milvus during restore is almost not using resource , only the pod with the backup-tool seems to do something:

```
k top pods -n milvus --sort-by=cpu
NAME                                   CPU(cores)   MEMORY(bytes)
milvus-backup-mycluster               1002m          330Mi
mycluster-datanode-5788666898-jb47f    777m          855Mi
mycluster-rootcoord-687cf4cb9-wp6n8     76m          132Mi
mycluster-querycoord-c47b99b8c-hflsc    40m          137Mi
mycluster-datacoord-84657c87df-zf9ld    27m          207Mi
mycluster-proxy-78d487487b-v4x22        20m          127Mi
mycluster-proxy-78d487487b-ntsjk        20m          134Mi
mycluster-etcd-2                        20m          148Mi
mycluster-etcd-1                        19m          137Mi
mycluster-etcd-0                        19m          134Mi
mycluster-pulsar-broker-0               19m          1465Mi
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can increase the datanode number and change parallelism config in backup.yaml.

```
backup:
  parallelism: 
    # Collection level parallelism to restore
    restoreCollection: 2
```

Comment: there is only one big collection ,  this looks to help when there are more then one ...

Comment: It works not only in collection level, but also one collection with large data. Actually it controls the concurrency of Bulkinsert calls. Data is restored by batch calls of Bulkinsert.

Comment: testing abit parallelism.restoreCollection didn't help too much with different values , holwever  it looks parallelism.copydata parameter helped to speed up taking backup , but didnt help with restore

Answer (score 1):

The recovery speed depends on bulk insert performance. During recovery, increase the number of datanode to improve bulk insert speed

Comment: maybe I missed to add above the rest 7x of  the data nodes cpu/memory  they look almost not used ...